# Container Managed Security for Web APplication

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-ee, security

I am completely new to Container managed security and need some help with configuring it in my web application.

I want to restrict access to the jsp's within my web application. This is how i have configured security in my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>PrivilegedConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>JSP Files</web-resource-name>
        <description>All the jsp files in the web application</description>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>PrivilegedRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>BasicRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>This is a privileged role. Has access to everything in the web app</description>
    <role-name>PrivilegedRole</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My questions are :

What is the purpose of realm-name in the login-config element?
Where do i configure the username, passwords and map the users to the roles?

When i try to access a jsp within my web application, i get asked for a username and password. What do i give there? And how does this security mechanism work?

I am completely new to security, so I will be grateful if someone can point me to a nice article which explains the basics of configuring security and how it actually works?

Answer (score 4):

> Q: "What is the purpose of realm-name in the login-config element?"

From the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxj.html):

> A **realm** is a security policy domain defined for a web or application server. A realm contains a collection of users, who may or may not be assigned to a group.

The behaviour as defined thus in the current [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315):

> HTTP Basic Authentication, which is based on a username and password,
>   is the authentication mechanism defined in the HTTP/1.0 specification.
>   A web server requests a web client to authenticate the user. As part
>   of the request, the web server passes the realm (a string) in which
>   the user is to be authenticated. The web client obtains the username
>   and the password from the user and transmits them to the web server.
>   The web server then authenticates the user in the specified realm.

> Q: "Where do i configure the username, passwords and map the users to the roles?"

This is container specific. That is, each server vendor is free to define how users/groups are defined and how this information is configured. There is usually more than one way to do this.

Users and groups are often defined in a directory. The server is then configured to use this directory and the administrator will map the application roles at deployment time.

A developer Tomcat test server might use a flat file; a production WebSphere server might hook into the company Exchange directory via LDAP.

Refer to your server documentation for more.

*You could do worse than follow the [Oracle Java EE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/index.html) tutorial with Netbeans and Glassfish, but be aware of the steps that are specific to that vendor's products.*