# AD Integration with a 3rd Party Web App

Tags: active-directory, integration, authentication

I am currently working on a Third Party Web Application which is internally hosted. (We own the App Server and the DB )

We need the sign on or User Authentication to be integrated on to AD. Vendors may able to get this working obviously with a  cost. I was wondering if anyone can put me on the right direction, may be the steps i should take to do this with the local development teams.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say virtually no chance. Is that webapp using any `mod_auth` in Apache?

Comment: No, It is on Weblogic server

Comment: If you use Container Managed Security, then it should be possible.

Comment: I am not clear what you meant, well I am a PM, so it could be really nice if you could be a bit descriptive..

Comment: And also, we still need to look in to the app login logic to tackle the user level security with in the application.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7818968/696632) question and the links within.